# Processing for large scale networking animation?

Tags: animation, qgis-processing

I am looking to create an animation of network connections, something very similar to this: http://vimeo.com/16897839. Let's say I have a huge database (millions of rows), that includes

> source location, destination location, timestamp

, and I want to create a timelapse animation of all the interactions going on, is it possible to animate this on the fly, or does it have to be saved frame by frame and then rendered into a video?

I have been playing around with Processing, and it seems that animating anything > 5000 objects, the animation becomes too laggy to view in real time.

I wanted to originally allow the viewer to select certain settings, and have the animation change depending on the filters, but I'm assuming if I have to render the image and record as video than that is not possible.